# Control Panel advanced search?

Tags: control-panel

Is it possible to use the search in the CP to search let's say by id? Or even one of the fields?

Thanks in advance,
Sidney

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search any of your fields using the syntax "fieldHandle: search term".

See http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/searching for more info.

Comment: jeez, how could I not see that in the docs?! Sorry for the stupid question and thanks for your answer...

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for entry IDs though...any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a new plugin that lets you do just this: https://plugins.craftcms.com/omnisearch

Full disclosure: I'm the author of this plugin.